# .NET MVC 4 Routing

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm kinda new to MVC 4, and I have a problem with my custom routing. I want to use slashes (/) in my URL instead of question marks (?).

This is my code:

**MapRoute:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Organisation",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{startindex}/{begin}/{end}/{type}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Organisation", action = "getOrganisations" }
);
```

**ActionLink:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Organisation", "getOrganisations", "Organisation", new { startindex = 0, begin= "a", end= "f", type = "all" }, null)
```

**URL I get:**

```
http://localhost:1566/Organisation/getOrganisations?startindex=0&begin=a&end=f&type=all
```

**URL I want:**

```
http://localhost:1566/Organisation/getOrganisations/0/a/f/all
```

**SOLUTION**

I found how to do it. This is how:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Org","Organisation",new { startindex = 0, begin= "a", end= "f", type= "all" })
```

Basically, you can use the `RouteLink` which takes the route name and route parameters as parms :)

**Edit (for Justin)**

```
  public ActionResult getOrganisations(int startindex, string begin, string end, string type)
    {
        List<'stored procedure'> retList= new List<'stored procedure'>();
        retList= Model.GetOrganisations(startindex, Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["pagesize"].Value), begin, end, type);
        return View(retList);
    }
```

Comment: I thought you don't need to say startindex, begin, etc. anymore, you can just assign new {param1, param2, etc.}

Comment: Can you show the code for `getOrganisations`?

Comment: You should move your solution into a new answer, instead of posting it in your question.

Comment: Move the solution to an answer and then we'll reopen it (the answer should not be in the question).